# I need assistance with my css, to obtain Content over display block. This is needed to add a title

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="about-buttonback"><div class="about-button"></div></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.about-button {
    color:#fff;  
    content: "Calender";  
    Display: block;  
    position: absolute;  
    width: 860px;  
    height: 40px;  
    top:5px;  
    left:5px;  
    text-indent: -9999px;  
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;  
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;  
    border-radius: 6px;  
    background-color: #d1d2d4;  
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#323232), to(#2a2829));  
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000, #2a2829);  
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000, #2a2829);  
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000, #2a2829);  
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #2a2829);  
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;  
    }

 .about-buttonback {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 870px;
    height: 50px;
    top:0px;
    left: 35px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #d1d2d4;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6b6b6b), to(#000));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4b4b4b, #000);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4b4b4b, #000);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4b4b4b, #000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4b4b4b, #000);
}
```

I am trying to do more over a overlay with a title over the blocks. I need the content to say Calender but it is not showing up over the blocks. Any suggestions?

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you won't need `display: block;`, and secondly, you are not able to see the text because you are using `text-indent: -9999px` which will just move any text in that `block` out of the viewport.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9FSYE/)

Also, make sure you wrap the `position: absolute;` elements under `position: relative;` container, else they will mess up your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Do this thing :-
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YL3HM/)

```
<div class="about-button">Calendar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the content to say Calender over the blocks for that if you add any text in Div
let's say "`**<div class="about-button">Calendar </div>**`" but text will not going to show after this too because you added " *text-indent: -9999px;* " to the both of the classes which you should need to remove in order to let your text display over the blocks.